# Ionic xcode building failed

Tags: angular, xcode, ionic-framework

i started an Ionic Project,

and run these comands to run Xcode.

1.ionic build,
2.npx cap add ios
3.ionic cap sync
4.npx cap copy ios
5.ionic cap open ios

The xCode is open, the 'Pods' on the left is red and i get this when i try to build it

[image: Here is a screenshot of the xCode when i run 'ionic cap open ios' and press the run butotn]

I tried some pod installs, i tried to clean cache